# count repeated date as one in excel

Tags: excel, count-unique

i want to count working days in a week by mentioned dates only like in picture only 4 working days will be considered in filtered data "year, month, and Week are derived by induction date column.[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdGSq.png)

Comment: Hi, your question needs more information.  Can you have a look at the help center on ideas of how to improve your question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help.  Are you wanting to get the week number based on a specified date?  `weeknum()` will do the trick.  Are you wanting to calculate time between two dates? `datedif()` will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Do want that repeated dates are considered into the counting or not? Anyway, you could apply workday formula (=WORKDAY (start_date, days, [holidays])) in an additional column and count from there, adding or criteria with IF formula or other logic to exclude repeated dates if you do not want to consider them.

Comment: by viewing the example i just want to count the dates mentioned in the data not every date in a week and i also want to count repeated dates as 1 so i can count there are 4 days mentioned in selected week.